# Facebook like button temporarily deform the page on mobile

Tags: html, facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

I've inserted the **Like** button on the mobile version of my website, but when it loads, it generates a big space that disappear almost instantly, but it is very annoying since it moves the text that a person is reading.

The code that I use for the button (html5 version) is

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

[This](http://www.primapaginaonline.it/2014/09/01/ascoli-picchio-buona-prima-perez-rigore-regala-i-tre-punti-a-pistoia/) is an example page where you can see the problem

Answer (score 0):

Within the iFrame of that widget there are two height values being applied, one of 1000px (height tag) and one of 20px (inline css), this appears to be what could be causing the jump you are referring to.

Comment: I don't think that it is related to the problem. The jump have the height of 134px